# How to SUMIF if cell is colored?

Tags: excel, vba

I found an user defined function online that may be useful for my case but I'm not entirely sure how it works. Please bear with me as I'm still a learner of VBA.

The function goes like this:

```
Function IsCellColored(CellRange As Range) As Variant
Application.Volatile

Dim Result() As Variant
ReDim Result(1 To 1, 1 To CellRange.Cells.Count)
Dim i As Integer

i = 1
For Each rCell In CellRange
   Result(1, i) = (rCell.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone)
   i = i + 1
Next rCell

IsCellColored = Result

End Function
```

Suppose I have a set of data in Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row) that I want the sum of the colored cells.

Conditions:

1. If cell in Range is colored then get the sum of the colored cells in Range("D1")
2. If cell in Range is not colored (ColorIndex = xlNone) then Range("D1").Value = 0

How do I edit/make the function work in my case? And, what is the formula I should use to get the sum?

Edit:

```
Public Sub sumBasedOnColor(ws As Worksheet)

Dim rg As Range

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        Set rg = .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    
    Dim v As Single
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In rg
        If c.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
            v = v + c.Value
        End If
    Next
    
    ws.Range("D1") = v
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: this function won't recalculate if you change a cell color.

Comment: You mean you want to sum all values from column D if column B is coloured? What is the condition that cells in column B are colored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sum values from column D you can use this code:

```vb
Public Sub sumBasedOnColor(ws as Worksheet)

Dim rg As Range
With ws
    Set rg = .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
End With

Dim v As Single
Dim c As Range
For Each c In rg
    If c.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
        v = v + c.Value
    End If
Next

ws.Range("D1") = v
End Sub
```

The code looks into each cell of column B - if it is colored - it takes the value and adds it to v.

You can call the sub e.g. like this:

```vb
Sub runAll()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    sumBasedOnColor ws
Next
End Sub
```

`v` will always start by 0 when calling with a new worksheet.

Comment: Thanks for helping out! I apologise that I could have been narrating wrongly in my question. The output that I actually wanted is just to sum up the figures in the colored cells in Column B, then return the summed value in Cell D1. If no cell is colored in Column B,  then return zero in Cell D1.

Comment: I updated the code. it now sums the values of column B and writes the result into D1

Comment: It's working flawlessly now. Please let me know if I need to start a new thread for this follow-up question. Basically, this code works on Activesheet and I modified it to loop through certain sheets in the workbook with the same data range. Now I encounter another issue: when I run the macro, it simply adds up all the values ACROSS the sheet (cumulative sum) instead of just sums up the data range of Activesheet only. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I updated the code so that you have to pass the worksheet. Does this help you?

Comment: I updated my codes in OP with your suggestion, but it still counts cumulative sum instead of sum for single sheet.

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: I used ALT+F8 and ran the macro directly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256603/discussion-between-ike-and-jeffch).

Comment: Thanks! Set this as answer. But I'm still interested to know why the `Sub sumBasedonColor` has to be called externally from another Sub instead of inside the Sub itself with `For` loop...

Comment: You could call it from inside - it is a more readable and easier to maintain way of coding. Each sub has exactly one task. And you would be able to call `sumBasedOnColor` from another routine - if necessary.